# Expressing "keep/bring in line" in German"

Tags: translation, word-usage, english-to-german, german-to-english

I am having troubles expressing "bringing/keeping someone in line" in German. This is synonymous with, "to keep somebody in control", or in German, closely related to "jemanden gefügig machen". In dictionaries, I see "jemanden auf Linie bringen/halten" here: https://www.dict.cc/?s=Linie+halten , here: https://de.pons.com/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/auf+Linie+bringen, and a few other places as well.

The problem is, there are no accompanying examples with these sentences, and a colleague told me that this was incorrect usage of the phrase. To make sure, do the following translations then work?

1. Eltern müssen manchmal bestimmt sein, um Kinder auf Linie zu halten

1.1 Parents must sometime be firm in order to keep kids in line (under control).

2. Der Aussenminister versuchte Land X durch Bedrohungen in Linie zu bringen.

2.1. The foreign minister tried to bring country X in line (get them to behave) through threats.

Comment: 1.: Eher "bestimmt auftreten" als "bestimmt sein", letzteres ist zweideutig. 2.: ... auf Linie bringen. Und doch, auf Linie bringen, insbes. in der Politik sehr verbreitet, oder auch "in der Spur sein", Spur i.S.v. Gleisen wird so benutzt. Was schlägt denn Dein Kollege vor?

Comment: Danke... I used it in the context with kids...to "keep the kids in line" so that they don't misbehave in certain situations. Can you use it in this context as well?

Comment: Nicht _in Linie_ verwendet man, sondern da, wo es paßt, _auf Linie_.

Comment: One issue here is "bring into line" more commonly means to make something/someone conform to a common standard. Wiktionary has the example "These changes will bring the country's anti-piracy laws into line with the rest of the European Union." I'm not sure if there's a difference between "bring into line" and "bring in line". Unless you're looking for a similar idiom, I'd suggest first rephrasing the English to not use the phrase and then translating the new version into German.

Comment: @RDBury Thank you for this excellent clarification with "conform to a common standard". This clarifies the matter for me. I understand that direct translations should be avoided, but when phrases look so similar between the two languages it can be difficult to see the fine differences.

Comment: You're welcome. Learning languages would be so much simpler without having do deal with idioms; even just recognizing an idiom in your own language can be tricky. Occasionally there are idioms that translate directly from one language to another; 'take part" = *teilnehmen* is one example I ran across. But that kind of thing is a rare exception rather than the rule.

Comment: There is also the nautical periphrase "einnorden" to express that someone needs new behavioural directions, like a fixed mounted compass that's being set up with little magnets to have the needle deviate less in it's respective environment with all those disturbances and distractions around.

Answer (score 5):

I can't remember hearing the expression "auf/in Linie", and it feels strange. Maybe it is a translation of the English expression, with is quite common these days.

I would use the expression "im Zaum halten". "Zaum" or "Zaumzeug" means "bridle" and as such expresses the control. Originally control of the horse, but it can also be used for children or subordinates. I personally wouldn't use it for another country, because the other country is supposed to be independent and not under control of someone else.

Answer (score 2):

All occurrences I remember of *auf Linie bringen* (see [DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/r/?corpus=public;q=auf%20linie%20bringen) for further examples) were in context of party politics, therefore [Stern](https://www.stern.de/politik/deutschland/diskussion-ueber-frauenquote-merkel-will-cdu-laenderchefs-wieder-auf-parteilinie-bringen-3489492.html)

> Merkel will CDU-Länderchefs wieder auf Parteilinie bringen.

Since the emphasis here is an alignment with a strict framework (as here party agenda), I guess it derives from military marching formation. It is not covering a general well-mannered behavior, which the English term seems to convey according to your examples.
This regulating effect is also addressed by:

> In die Schranken (ver-)weisen

For the *keeping in line* aspect *im Zaum halten* is already coverd in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you present *jemanden gefügig machen* as a possible translation I offer *jemanden an der kurzen Leine halten*.

Besides, I could imagine *jemanden auf Kurs bringen* resp. *jemanden auf Kurs halten*.  And *jemanden bei der Stange halten* if the problem is to *let someone stick to something* e.g a task/job/idea.

*jemandem Einhalt gebieten* and *jemanden bändigen* are further alternatives.

Edit:
I have made some more research and found the following [documented](https://context.reverso.net/%C3%BCbersetzung/deutsch-englisch/in+die+Spur+bringen) translation of *to get someone in line*: *jemanden in die Spur bringen*

Comment: "Jemandem Einhalt gebieten" means that you want to stop somebody from doing something specific. It doesn't fit the examples in the question.